# How to build a Python function to build Pandas DataFrames dynamically?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe in pandas that I need to use to create other dataframes from.

the dataframe contains naics codes along with related data. I am trying to create a new dataframe per code in essence and getting stuck on an error.

fdf is a dataframe with 2 digit numbers ie: 10,11,12,13.

I want to loop through this dataframe to query and build many others. Here is what I have so far:

```
for x in fdf:
    'Sdf' + str(x) = df[df['naics'].astype(str).str[2:4]==str(x)]
```

if I run this by itself:

```
df[df['naics'].astype(str).str[2:4]==str(57)]
```

it returns the dataframe I want, but I am not sure how to build this into a function.

'SyntaxError: can't assign to function call' is the error I get.  I think the issue is how I am trying to dynamically build the dataframe name?

any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You may want to store those df in dict , or if you do want save them in memory check with local()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it with use of dictionary.

```
df_list = {}
for x in fdf:
    df_list[str(x)] = df[df['naics'].astype(str).str[2:4]==str(x)]
```